# Understanding Javascript's difference between calling a function, and returning the function but executing it later

Tags: javascript, prototype, scope, this

I'm trying to understand the difference between `foo.bar()` and `var fn = foo.bar; fn();`

I've put together a little example, but I dont totally understand why the failing ones actually fail.

```
var Dog = function() {
    this.bark = "Arf";
};

Dog.prototype.woof = function() {
    $('ul').append('<li>'+ this.bark +'</li>');
};

var dog = new Dog();


// works, obviously
dog.woof();

// works
(dog.woof)();

// FAILS
var fnWoof = dog.woof;
fnWoof();


// works
setTimeout(function() {
    dog.woof();
}, 0);

// FAILS
setTimeout(dog.woof, 0);
```

Which produces:

- Arf
- Arf
- undefined
- Arf
- undefined

On JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6Vdg/1/

So it appears that snapping off a function causes it to remove it's context.  Ok.  But why then does `(dog.woof)();` work?

It's all just a bit confusing figuring out whats going on here.  There are obviously some core semantics I'm just not getting.

Comment: +1, I would have said (dog.woof)(); will fail. wtf

Comment: My only guess is some bizarre on the fly "optimization" of the "compiler".  But I don't know anywhere near enough about javascript runtimes to understand it.

Comment: I think the answer is really simple. `(xxx)` returns the result of the expression inside. Since the expression is dog.woof the call operator () operates on that. You could do `(dog.undefined || dog.nothing || dog.woof)()` and it would work too.

Comment: @Hemlock, fail as in lose its implied object, in the same way var fnWoof = dog.woof; loses its implied object.

Comment: @chris Yeah, I got that. The context isn't lost in that case, it just returns the result of the expression, context and all.

Comment: The reason (I think) is that the Javascript interpreter has more information than we do. It knows that the parent object of `woof` is `dog`, therefore assigns it as `this`. When you assign `woof` to a local variable it no longer has a parent, which the interpreter also knows, and thus assigns `window` to `this` instead. When you pass `dog.woof` to a function as a callback (such as your `setTimeout` example), `woof` is assigned to a local variable that is one of the named parameters of the called function, again losing its parent object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with context and the `this` keyword.

Functions don't inherently "belong" to an object. For example, I can create a cat object and copy the woof function over:

```
var cat = {
    bark: "meow",
    woof = Dog.prototype.woof
};
```

Now `cat.woof` will give me "meow". Because of this flexibility of functions to be copied and re-assigned, `var fnWoof = dog.woof;` disassociates `fnWoof` from `dog` - it has no context. Therefore the context, and the `this` keyword, defaults to `window`. Since `window` doesn't have a `bark` property, you get `undefined`.

If you give window a bark property:

```
window.bark = "Arf";
```

Then your code will work (although erroneously):

```
fnWoof(); // "Arf"
```

To make it work as expected, you can pass in the context *explicity*:

```
fnWoof.call(dog);
```

Comment: +1, here is a jsFiddle update showing the use of 'call' http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/D6Vdg/4/

Comment: So how does `this` get mapped the right instance in the invocations that work?  In ruby terms, is `this` always set to the receiver object that you are calling the method on?  I guess is it the dot notation `anyobj.anyfn()` the makes `this = anyobj` inside `anyfn()`?  And therefore, `anyobj.anyfn()` is simply syntax sugar for `anyobj.anyfn.call(anyobj)`.  And without a "receiver" it defauls to `window`, making it `window.anyfn.call(window)`.  Do I have that right?

Comment: @Squeegy, yes that's exactly right and a very nice way to put it. Although, without the receiver, it defaults to `someFn.call(window)`, or whatever the reference is

Comment: Thanks, this helps.  I didn't realize it was the dot syntax that assigns `this`.  I assumed it was some magic with `promotype` and `new`.  This makes far more sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `foo.bar()`, the function is called with the value of `foo` as the value of `this`.
With `var fn = foo.bar; fn();` the function is called with `null` as the value of `this` which is automatically coerced to the global object when `this` is evaluated.

The relevant portion of the spec is below.  See especially 7.  If it's a property reference (i.e. an expression like `a.b` or `a[b]`), then thisValue becomes the base of the property reference.

### 11.2.3 Function Calls

The production CallExpression : MemberExpression Arguments is evaluated as follows:

1. List item
2. Let ref be the result of evaluating MemberExpression.
3. Let func be GetValue(ref).
4. Let argList be the result of evaluating Arguments, producing an internal list of argument values (see 11.2.4).
5. If Type(func) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
6. If IsCallable(func) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
7. If Type(ref) is Reference, then

> a.   If IsPropertyReference(ref) is true, then Let thisValue be GetBase(ref).
>
> b.   Else, the base of ref is an Environment Record so Let thisValue be the result of calling the ImplicitThisValue concrete method of GetBase(ref).

Answer (score 0):

`dog.woof` has to be run in the context of an instance of `Dog` because it depends on `this.bark`, as you seem to understnad

```
Dog.prototype.woof2 = function() {$('ul').append('<li>'+ 'arf' +'</li>'); };
```

If you replace those failing `woof` with `woof2` it could run anywhere

As for the case `(dog.woof)();` vs `var fnWoof = dog.woof; fnWoof();` it is kind of counterintuitive.  The difference is the assignment.  The first case still runs it as belonging to `dog`, whereas the second does not.  It is assignment time that takes `woof`and puts it into a different constant, not merely accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a particularly confusing bit of code for a number of reasons that I'll try to explain.

First... the setTimeOut method is a bit of a PITA as explained here: http://ifhere.org/javascript

The issue you're having with the `setTimeout(dog.woof, 0);` is because of setTimeOut, not your code (well not entirely your code).

The main issue tho is that the `dog.woof` is getting executed, it's the value of `bark` that is undefined and the reason it's undefined is because you are passing the function itself as the parameter, not the function as it is attached to the variable dog.

in both:

```
var fnWoof = dog.woof;
```

and

```
setTimeout(dog.woof, 500);
```

you are passing the ***function definition*** as opposed to the instantiated object and it's associated function.